# Resolution when clauses contain more than 1 complementary literals

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat

Let's assume that we have clauses $(l_1 \lor l_2 \lor l_3), (\neg l_1 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_4), (l_1 \lor l_2 \lor l_5), (\neg l_1 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_6)$, where both $l_1$ and $l_2$ are complementary literals for the clauses.

If we apply the resolution technique for $l_1$ we'll get clauses

$(l_2 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_3 \lor l_4)$,
$(l_2 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_3 \lor l_6)$,
$(l_2 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_5 \lor l_4)$,
$(l_2 \lor \neg l_2 \lor l_5 \lor l_6)$

How to proceed with $l_2$ from here?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? It is very odd to read 2 complementary literals in the same clause:  $(l_2 \lor \neg l_2 \lor ...)$. Thus what is the resolution technique you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Clauses containing both a variable and its negation are not useful, since they're always correct. You can just ignore them.

Furthermore, you CNF is satisfiable - for example, you can set all variables to TRUE. So it's not completely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My intention was to understand how, for instance, DP algorithm deals with the clauses were two complementary literals exist. So for instance DP automatically drops off the these resolved clauses that contain both a literal and its negation?

Comment: Yes, these clauses are useless.